# Reconstructing a pattern match so that I can call methods on it?

Tags: scala

I just cannot figure out a way to google this.  I have, for example, code like this:

```
import dispatch._
object Main extends App {

  val svc = url("http://www.php.net/license")
  val src:Promise[String] = Http(svc OK as.String) recover {
    case StatusCode(301) => "got the 301, now where the heck should I go?"
    case error => "caught error:" + error.toString
  }

  println(src())
}
```

From the dispatch package, recover takes a PartialFunction[Throwable,A] where A ends up being a String in my case.  That url always returns 301, presumably with a message telling me where I should go instead.  But in pattern matching on it, how do I access the plethora of methods that are inherited by statuscode that could give me an idea of what went wrong?

In haskell I'd do it like this:

```
case x of
  sc@StatusCode(301) -> getMessage(sc)
  error -> ...
```

If it is not possible to get the original object in scala, is there some way I could have written this code so that it would have worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry I'm a complete idiot.  I didn't even think to try this even after writing my haskell solution:

```
case sc@StatusCode(301) => sc.getMessage
```